# convert decimal to string and add comma and separator

Tags: .net, decimal, converters, arcobjects

What would be the easiest way to convert a decimal to string, and add a comma and spaces. It has to convert land parcels area, in square meters.
It can be 1456, 25678, 364789 or 2548978 m².. It depends on the size of the parcel.
I'd like to convert it to obtain this result :

1456 = 1 456,0

25678 = 25 678,0

364789 = 364 789,0

2548978 = 2 548 978,0..

I tried this :

```
myvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(MyFeature.Value(MyFeature.Fields.FindField("MyAreaField"))).ToString("# ### ###,0")
```

But 312410 gave this result : 31 2 410

Can you help me please?

Comment: Sounds like you could use [NumberFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx), assuming that this format is not covered by an existing Culture setting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
var myValue = Convert.ToDecimal(MyFeature.Value(MyFeature.Fields.FindField("MyAreaField")));
var sValue = string.Format("{0:0 0,0}", myValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this, and it work

```
        Dim nfi = New NumberFormatInfo() With { _
            .NumberGroupSeparator = " ", _
            .NumberDecimalSeparator = "," _
        }

    Convert.ToDecimal("1231231232").ToString("#,#.0#", nfi)
    Convert.ToDecimal("123456,1").ToString("#,#.0#", nfi)
    Convert.ToDecimal("123456").ToString("#,#.0#", nfi)
    Convert.ToDecimal("123").ToString("#,#.0#", nfi)
```

It gives this :

```
1 231 231 232,0
1 234 561,0
123 456,0
123,0
```